# FileUriExposed exception error

Tags: java, android, file, uri

im getting the following error in my logcat.

```
: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/download/AllCast.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

it only happening on some devices ie marsh mellow and nougat.

this is where error occurs

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + newnamestring)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);
```

ive tried adding this line of code

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

also tried this in my app class

```
 StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    builder.detectFileUriExposure();
```

can anybody tell me what im doing wrong. thanks

EDIT****

Ok guys im trying to get @CommonsWare answer to work i can get the file to download fin to the provider folder. but then my app crashes when it trys to handle the intent. here is my new log cat

```
05-07 16:25:35.784 8715-8715/com.example.harrops.h20droidapp2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: mypackagename, PID: 8715
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at my package name.Casting_Apps$DownloadFileFromURL.onPostExecute(Casting_Apps.java:273)
```

which leads me to section of code

```
File newFile = null;

        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = newFile.getName().substring(newFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getBaseContext(), "my package name", newFile);
                intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, type);
            } else {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile), type);
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_VIEW_ATTACHMENT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No activity found to open this attachment.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38200282/115145

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare was looking at this yesterday. im going to have a go at it now. will be back in touch soon with a result lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer i went for.. thanks @CommonsWare for the help

```
File toInstall = new File(appDirectory, appName + ".apk");
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", toInstall);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
intent.setData(apkUri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
activity.startActivity(intent)
} else {
Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

}